# In Excel how can I use IF Function with more then 70 conditions or is there any other way to do that

Tags: excel, excel-formula, export-to-excel

I'm trying to add if function with more then 70+ conditions. How can I do that or is there any other way to do that? I'm sharing screenshot.

Please help.

[image]

Comment: Is it to check that the value in column B also appears in column G?  If it is you could use something like `=IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH(B2,$G$2:$G$15,0))),"Home","Work")`

Comment: Use `MATCH()` function.

Comment: Please explain what you *want to achieve* - I am pretty sure there will be another solution than a 70+If-Condition ...

Answer (score 1):

You have the tendency to nest `IF`-clauses enormously. I would advise you to write the whole idea down and try to simplify it, as you can see from following example:
I have three cells ("F2", "G2" and "H2"), all can have two values ("Work" or "Home"), and I have created two formulas to calculate a result:

```
Formula1 : =IF(F2="Home","Home",IF(F3="Home","Home",IF(F4="Home","Home","Work")))
Formula2 : =IF(AND(F2="Work",F3="Work",F4="Work"),"Work","Home")
```

You see: "Formula1" is based on three nested `IF`-clauses, while "Formula2" only one.

Yet, both formulas yield the same result!